# Configuring VirtualHost together with localhost on VertrigoServ 2.29

Tags: apache, virtualhost, virtual-hosts

I use [VertrigoServ](http://vertrigo.sourceforge.net/) as my Apache - MySql - PHP stack.
Up till now, I used to put all sites in the /www folder and access them by the url `http://localhost/sitename`.

Now I'm developing a multilanguage site. The site's idiom will be set according to the domain. So I need to set up a virtual host for this site, but I need to still have access to the other sites using the localhost url.

I added the following code to conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost dev.mysite.com.br dev.mysite.uy>
    ServerAdmin admin@mysite.com.br
    DocumentRoot "C:\sites\mysite"
    ServerName dev.mysite.com.br
    ServerAlias dev.mysite.uy
</VirtualHost>
```

My default localhost root folder is `C:\sites`

An example of the httpd.conf used by VertrigoServ can be seen [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4169356/httpd.conf), and this and example of the [vertrigo.conf](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4169356/vertrigo.conf) file.

With this config, I need to put a copy of vertrigo.conf inside `C:\sites\mysite\conf`.
Yet, after this is done, a request to `http://localhost` serves the site specified by this VirtualHost.

So, how can I use virtual hosts and still access older projects the old way? If I could avoid copying vertrigo.conf, it would be good!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I don't know exactly how I solved this but it worked.

I added the following to the end of the file `conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost dev.mysite.com.br dev.mysite.uy>
    ServerAdmin admin@mysite.com.br
    DocumentRoot "C:/sites/mysite"
    ServerName dev.mysite.com.br
</VirtualHost>
```

Then I 'Shutdown and exit' VertrigoServ and executed it again as Windows administrator.

It seems VertrigoServ has a default configuration (localhost) for anything that is not in a VirtualHost.